# Flutter How to open soft input keyboard when i have physical keyboard too?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, barcode-scanner

I use RawKeyboardListener widget for listening barcode scanner, but when scanner connecting to device, soft input keyboard don't work.
How i can open soft input keyboard, when i use scanner?

This code not helpful:

```
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');
```

or

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
```

RawKeyboardListener example

```
RawKeyboardListener(
              focusNode: _focusNode,
              onKey: (event) {
                    if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
                      if (event.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
                        log('ENTER');
                        _barcodeText = '';
                      } else {
                        log('Event data keyLabel ${event.data.keyLabel}');
                        _barcodeText += event.data.keyLabel;
                      }
                      log('barCodeText: $_barcodeText');
                    }
              },
    )
```

Comment: How did you use the RawKeyboardListener widget to listen to the barcode scanner not working either.

Comment: When i use scanner, text writes from scanner, but system keyboard don't work

Comment: If you want to use both the barcode scanner and the system, you can use the textfield widget. Could you add your code to your question?

Comment: I use TextFormField widget, but in smaller android version  6.0.0 it's work not correctly, and RawKeyboardListener widget i use for write data in state without TextField widget

Comment: I use textfield to read barcodes, but this time I can't close the keyboard, it's the opposite of your situation. I can't get barcode results from RawKeyboardListener how did you do that?

Comment: I added example using RawKeyboardListener widget

Comment: event.data.keyLabel values return empty for me.. Do you why know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245290/discussion-between-nikolay-and-volkanustekidag).